# String#replaceAll(): Representing the end or beginning of a string in look-arounds?

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on an argument parser that will take a `String[]` of arguments and convert it into output usable by the program I'm working on. Arguments are separated by spaces, so in the text `here are some arguments`, each word is a separate argument. However, I figure that users may need to group words together, so I am adding this functionality in the form of backslashes at the ends of words.

In addition, because the program reads the arguments as a map and uses keywords to link values (think of command-line flags like `--password 123456` which can appear anywhere in the command), there needs to be a way of escaping arguments, which, for the sake of consistency, I have made `\<arg>`. This means that the regular expression which strips out backslashes should ignore those at the beginning of a string.

Another thing to consider is the ability to escape the grouping backslash with another backslash. This means that any backslash that follows another backslash should not be removed. For example, `two\\ arguments` becomes an array with `two\` and `arguments` as its elements.

Finally, I would like to leave backslashes in the middle of words untouched. This means that the regular expression should remove backslashes that are at the end of a string or that are followed by a space.

With these rules,

- `these\ are\ together` would become one argument with the backslashes taken out;
- `back\slash` would remain as it is;
- `\test\\` would become `\test\`; and
- `\test` would remain as it is.

I am currently using look-arounds to achieve the effect I would like:

```
String[] args = input.split("(?<!(?<!\\\\)\\\\) ");

for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i)
    args[i] = args[i].replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\\\(?= )", "");
```

Initially, I split the arguments using the expression `'(?<!(?<!\\)\\) '` (without the apostrophes), thus taking care of the grouping. Now the parser moves on to stripping the backslashes, a task which the above expression does not handle.

This leads to the regular expression `(?<!\\)\\(?= )`. In general, when this expression is used in `String#replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\\\(?= )", "")`, some of the wanted effects are achieved:

- `these\ are\ together` becomes `these are together`; and
- `back\slash` remains as it is.

However, this expression becomes problematic once a backslash is found at the beginning or at the end of a string. For example, `\test\\` is incorrectly parsed as `test\\`, because the first backslash is not preceded by another backslash, and the last backslash is not followed by a space. After hours of searching Google using queries like `regular expression represent empty character`, `regex ignore start of string`, and `regular expression escape if not preceded by anything` (each to no avail), I decided to come ask you guys for help. So, here is my question:

*Is it possible to represent the end and beginning of a String in look-arounds?* (Alternatively, an empty character would work as well.)

I have already tried the `^`, `$`, and `\b` characters so that my expression looks like `(?<!(^|\b|\\))\\(?=($|\b| ))`, but this has no effect. (I've also tried having an empty literal, like `(?<!(|\\))\\(?=(| ))`.)

Any help is much, much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you expect to see for `"\test\\"` output?

Comment: Is string representing ``foo\\`` (yes literal with two backslashes) possible? If yes how would it look like as parameter of lets say `foo??? bar` when we would like to also escape space (what wee should put in place of `???`)? Would it be `foo\\\\\ bar`? And if we wouldn't want to escape also space should it look like `foo\\\\ bar`? If so then your split condition would be probably wrong `(?<!(?<!\\\\)\\\\)`. BTW this condition is same as `(?<!\\\\\\\\)` or maybe simpler `(?<!(\\\\){2})`.

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if we would have certainty of what kind of data you allow in your program and what data should never appear. I might have few ideas of how to help you but I need to know if some strings are possible or not, for instance is string like ``abc\ \\\def\\\\\ ghi\ \\ \\\ jk lmn\`` possible? If not which parts of it exactly? If yes how would you like this sentence to be parsed? If you would removed incorrect parts how would correct sentence look like and how should it be parsed?

Comment: Also it probably would be simpler to be consistent and make ``\`` special in entire string so if you would want to create literal ``\`` you would need to write it everywhere as ``\\``. This way you could just replace two ``\\`` with one ``\`` or `\(?= |$)` (backslash and space or end of string) with nothing. Code for something like this could look like `replaceAll("(\\\\)\\\\|\\\\)", "$1")` - first replace two backslashes with only first one (placed in group 1), and remove all single backslashes.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: `\test\` would be the desired output. @Pshemo Yes, I suppose it would probably be easier to do it that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `$` or `^` in **lookarounds** because:

- lookarounds are literally trying to ***assert that we can match some pattern***, either before or after the current position, while:
- `$` and `^` aren't really something you can match, they **themselves** are simply **assertions** too (*assert that we're at the **end*** (respectively: ***beginning***) *of the input*).

Thus, you could even see them as simple particular **lookarounds**. `(?<=^)` is simply written `^` and `(?=$)` is `$`.

In your case, you should simply handle that case where a `\` is at the end of the line by checking that additional condition `\\$` in your regex, which becomes:

```
((?<!\\)\\(?= )|\\$)
```

... or, as a **Java** `String`: `((?<!\\\\)\\\\(?= )|\\\\$)`

See a working example [here on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/bZ4yF6).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be treating all `\` as special characters like String in Java does. This way to create `\` literal you would need to use two `\\`.

Now instead of finding place to split you could just create rule which would accept as token string which is build from

- alphanumerics - for instance `\\w`
- two backslashes
- or backslash with space after it

Pattern for such combination can look like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+|(\\\\){2}|\\\\\\s)+");
```

Now to "normalize" it you would just need to replace two backslashes with one backslash and replace rest of backslashes (the single one) with nothing. You could do it with

```
replaceAll("(\\\\)\\\\|\\\\", "$1")
```

idea of this regex is to first try to find two backslashes and place first of them in group 1 so we could replace them with this first backslash. Since already matched backslashes can't be found (matched) again in same pass, single ones must be the unescaped ones and we want to get rid of them. Because for them only right side of regex from replaceAll will be found left side will be empty which means that there will be no match in group 1 so `$1` will return empty string as we wanted (replace single `\` with empty string).

Here is example of this solution

```
String data = "these\\ are\\ \\\\toge\\\\ther and these\\\\ \\not\\";
System.out.println("user input = "+data);
System.out.println("--------------");

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+|(\\\\){2}|\\\\\\s)+");
//find only combination of letters or two backslashes or backslash and space
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group().replaceAll("(\\\\)\\\\|\\\\", "$1"));
```

Output:

```
user input = these\ are\ \\toge\\ther and these\\ \not\
--------------
these are \toge\ther
and
these\
not
```